# How do I close window from javascript which was opened by Ionic Capacitor

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic-native, capacitor

I am opening window in my ionic app

```
 await Browser.open({url: environment.apiUrl + `/myurl`});
```

But then I want to close close that window it self when user complete certain action. I tried `window.close` but due to security issues it does not work.

How do I close that window?

Comment: Docs say Browser.close(), but only works on Web and iOS

Comment: @WillAlexander yes thats first thing but second i dont want to close from app, but from page I am opening.

Comment: are you using in-app-browser? `browser.on('loadstart').subscribe((res) => {
      console.log('loadStory', res);
      if (res.url == 'yourURlWhenUserDoneSomething') {
        browser.close();
      }
    }, err => {
      console.error(err);
    });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the way.

- Register [custom scheme](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/app#ios)
- In external app redirect `window.location.href="customschema://"`
- For iOS listen for **appUrlOpen** and close browser, for android as soon as you redirect to custom schema will close.

Place into app.component on app start

```
if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
  App.addListener('appUrlOpen', data => {
    if (data.url.indexOf('comflymarkonline://')> -1) {
      Browser.close();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Chrome WebView will block deeplinks that are not explicitly clicked by the user on Android. How did you manage to make `window.location.href="customschema://"` works on Android?

Comment: @didil I added button "Complete and close window", when user click it I am doing redirect

Comment: Android now deprecates using Deeplinks in favor of Universal links.